# Cannot enable pgsql remote connection

Tags: postgresql

#### Initial problem

I am trying to remotely connect myself to my pgsql database, but when I do

```
psql -h 192.168.0.121 -p 5432 my_pgsql_admin_username -d my_database
```

(192.168.0.121 being the address of the machine hosting the pgsql database), I got the tipical error :

```
psql: could not connect do server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "192.168.0.121" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432 ?
```

#### My configuration

My `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` already contains a `listen_adresses = '*'`.

My `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` contains the following rules :

```
local  all  postgres             peer
local  all  all                  peer
host   all  all  127.0.0.1/32    md5
host   all  all  192.168.0.0/24  md5
host   all  all  ::1/128         md5
```

A `sudo iptables -L` gives me :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.121        tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:postgresql state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.121        anywhere             tcp spt:postgresql dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED
```

I already restarted my postgresql (`sudo service postgresql restart`), and my iptables (`/etc/init.d/networking restart`). I also tried to replace `md5` by `trust` in my `pg_hba.conf`, without seeing any changes.

#### Weird behavior

In my `postgresql.conf` if I don't set `listen_adresses`, I can't remotely connect, but at least I can locally connect (with a simple `psql`), but if I set the `listen_adresses` varaible to anything (may it be `'*'` or `'localhost'`) then I'll still not be able to remotely connect, but I even won't be able to connect locally.

#### Question

What is going wrong here ? Is it a strange bug or did I just missed something in the configuration ?

#### System specs :

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 on a virtualBox
- PostGreSQL 9.5

Comment: May it be that you are connected via wifi and your remote address of machine starts with 10? If so, you need to include that as well. This is where I would look first: include additional rule in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just misspelled "listen_addresses" with only one 'd'. 4 hours of work wasted for ... being dumb and french I guess ...

Comment: The lesson to be learned from this: in case of problems, look into the PostgreSQL log. That would have told you what the problem was right away.